# Unable to resolve NULL driver for [Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager]. for lumen framework

Tags: php, laravel, email, lumen

Getting the error InvalidArgumentException Unable to resolve NULL driver for [Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager] on Lumen using smtp driver. I followed all the steps setting up Mail in the lumen documentation. Here is my env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=domain.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=username@domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@username@domain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Company name"
```

Added the mail.php from the laravel repo into the lumen.../config folder

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Mailer
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default mailer that is used to send any email
    | messages sent by your application. Alternative mailers may be setup
    | and used as needed; however, this mailer will be used by default.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mailer Configurations
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure all of the mailers used by your application plus
    | their respective settings. Several examples have been configured for
    | you and you are free to add your own as your application requires.
    |
    | Laravel supports a variety of mail "transport" drivers to be used while
    | sending an e-mail. You will specify which one you are using for your
    | mailers below. You are free to add additional mailers as required.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "ses",
    |            "postmark", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

added the following to my app.php in bootstrap

```
$app->register(Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class);
$app->configure('mail');
$app->configure('services');
$app->alias('mailer', Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::class);
$app->alias('mailer', Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer::class);
$app->alias('mailer', Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\MailQueue::class);
```

The implementation making sending the email

```
public function testMail()
    {
        Mail::to('username2@domain.com.com')->send(new MailableClass('George','Kindly note that your email has been sent'));
    }
```

MailableClass simply being a class that extends Mailable to build the view

i also did a data dump of the config('mail') which returned this

```
array:4 [▼
  "default" => "smtp"
  "mailers" => array:7 [▼
    "smtp" => array:8 [▼
      "transport" => "smtp"
      "host" => "username@domain.com"
      "port" => "465"
      "encryption" => "tls"
      "username" => "username@domain.com"
      "password" => "password"
      "timeout" => null
      "auth_mode" => null
    ]
    "ses" => array:1 [▶]
    "mailgun" => array:1 [▶]
    "postmark" => array:1 [▶]
    "sendmail" => array:2 [▶]
    "log" => array:2 [▶]
    "array" => array:1 [▶]
  ]
  "from" => array:2 [▶]
  "markdown" => array:2 [▶]
```

i check the Manager.php and TransportManager.php files in illuminate/mail
when i set the driver value of the driver function to "smtp" I able to pass to the createSmtpDriver() of TransportManager.php. You can see the respective codes here...

```
    /**
     * Get a driver instance.
     *
     * @param  string  $driver
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function driver($driver = "smtp") //originally $driver = null
    {
        $driver = $driver ?: $this->getDefaultDriver();

        if (is_null($driver)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
                'Unable to resolve NULL driver for [%s].', static::class
            ));
        }

        // If the given driver has not been created before, we will create the instances
        // here and cache it so we can return it next time very quickly. If there is
        // already a driver created by this name, we'll just return that instance.
        if (! isset($this->drivers[$driver])) {
            $this->drivers[$driver] = $this->createDriver($driver);
        }

        return $this->drivers[$driver];
    }
```

I did a dd in the createSmtpDriver()

```
       protected function createSmtpDriver()
    {
        $config = $this->app->make('config')->get('mail');
        **dd($config);**

        // The Swift SMTP transport instance will allow us to use any SMTP backend
        // for delivering mail such as Sendgrid, Amazon SES, or a custom server
        // a developer has available. We will just pass this configured host.
        $transport = new SmtpTransport($config['host'], $config['port']);

        if (isset($config['encryption'])) {
            $transport->setEncryption($config['encryption']);
        }

        // Once we have the transport we will check for the presence of a username
        // and password. If we have it we will set the credentials on the Swift
        // transporter instance so that we'll properly authenticate delivery.
        if (isset($config['username'])) {
            $transport->setUsername($config['username']);

            $transport->setPassword($config['password']);
        }

        // Next we will set any stream context options specified for the transport
        // and then return it. The option is not required any may not be inside
        // the configuration array at all so we'll verify that before adding.
        if (isset($config['stream'])) {
            $transport->setStreamOptions($config['stream']);
        }

        return $transport;
    }
```

the results of this dd was basically the results in config('mail') above and from that we can see the config['host'], config['port'] ..etc will return nothing  because they are in mailer so i thinking it should be config['mailer']['host'] instead... but these are all framework files so...

I will really appreciate the assistance figuring this out.. at a total loss what I am doing wrong. Thank you

oh right forgot I have also installed..

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I basically replaced the mail.php I got from Laravel repo to this basic one

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
    |            "sparkpost", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

And it works now